# extjs ie8 layout run failed

Tags: javascript, extjs, layout, internet-explorer-8

I have created an app based on the Desktop example in ExtJS 4.1.

Later my client decided to upgrade to ExtJS 5.1.

After some changes it works fine in all supported browsers except for IE8.
The problem is that when i create a new window and show it, I can see a "Layout run failed" in console.
I compared the desktop example from ExtJS 5.1 and my and found that in the example, the window object is created using w = new Ext.window.Window(config) and this works fine.

My code uses the approach from the Ext 4.1 and extend the Window class as below:

```
Ext.define('Project.user.forms.SearchForm', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
.....
});
```

So, when the window is created, the code is:
**w = new Project.user.forms.SearchForm()**

I tried even with a very simple form with no items at all, and the result is the same: Layout run failed.

Is there a way to fix this without having to change the code for all my forms?

Thank you,
Andrei

Comment: Have you tried setting 'frame: false'?

Comment: Yes, thanks, the same problem using frame: false.

Comment: There might be many reason for layout run failed I recommend you to read http://whatisextjs.com/extjs/debugging-extjs-layout-run-error